# Jaydebeapi and sslTrustStoreLocation

Tags: jdbc, db2, jaydebeapi

I connect to my db2 database with following URL:

```
jdbc:db2://myhost:9999/mydb:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=/home/my name/somekey.jks
```

using squirrel.

Now I'm trying to connect from python using jaydebeapi using the same URL string but it fails with

> jpype._exception.       SqlSyntaxErrorExceptionPyRaisable: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException:
>   [jcc][10165][10051][4.20.4] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://myhost:9999/mydb:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=/home/my name/somekey.jks.     ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

What is the recommended way to pass the key store file via jaydebeapi?

Comment: All property key-value pairs in the URL should end with semicolons, including the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get the same error

Comment: Try the new JayDeBeApi 1.0.0 feature passing a dictionary with properties (sslConnection, sslTrustStoreLocation and user, password) instead. Read the docstring of the connect method carefully.